# Css remove the bounce effect

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, overscroll

[image]

I am having the following problem on firefox macOs.

I solved the Chrome problem by putting this in the body:

```css
body {
  overscroll-behavior-y: none;
}
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Are you stating this is a default behavior, or is some type of event happening with adding elements in JS or CSS? I ask because it doesn't look exactly like scroll chaining the way the video shows. Have you tried `contain`?  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overscroll-behavior/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `overscroll-behavior: none;` instead of `overscroll-behavior-y: none;` as stated here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior?retiredLocale=de

Comment: The OP states in the post they do this without it working.

Comment: Yeah your right. Thats why I changed my answer a bit. On developer.mozilla they say you can use overscroll-behavior but not overscroll-behavior-y.
So firefox probably doesnt support the -y tag